# Design and analyze an efficient algorithm that, given n distinct integers, returns an element which is neither the smallest nor the largest

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to prepare for mock exam, could you please help me with possible solutions?
Design and analyze an efficient algorithm that, given n distinct integers, returns
an element which is neither the smallest nor the largest

Comment: You are getting downvotes because you showed no effort other then typing the question.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:sorting], why [tag:quicksort]?

Answer (score 2):

Straight forward and simple solution-
1)Randomly select any three integers from the list ,say p,q,r.

2)Return the element which is not maximum and minimum among p,q,r.
Since all elements in the given list are distinct.
Thus the solution is guaranteed for n>=3.

Comment: No need for the selection to be random, "Select any three" is sufficient, and likely more efficient (Ex: select the first three)

Comment: (The selection may be *arbitrary*.)

Answer (score 2):

As said elsewhere, the solution is the median of any three elements. As there can be $3$ outcomes, any solution based on comparison of the values must do at least $2$ comparisons. On the other hand, only $3$ different comparisons can be made. So far, we cannot tell if the worst-case requires $2$ or $3$ comparisons.

Now, WLOG, we can assume that the first comparison is $(a,b)$. For the second comparison, we can choose between $(a,c)$ and $(b,c)$. Then

- if we observe $a<b,a<c$, we still don't know which is the median element;
- if we observe $a<b,b>c$, we still don't know which is the median element.

In conclusion, the optimal solution (in the worst-case sense) must take $3$ comparisons.